# utop error: No such package: sexplib.syntax - required by `core.syntax'

Tags: emacs, ocaml, opam, utop

I'm trying to set up an emacs ocaml environment following the *Real World Ocaml* instructions [here](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions), but when I start utop I get the error:

```
No such package: sexplib.syntax - required by `core.syntax'
```

If I run: `ocamlfind list | grep sexp` from the command-line I get :

```
ppx_sexp_conv       (version: 113.24.00)
ppx_sexp_conv.expander (version: 113.24.00)
ppx_sexp_conv.expander.for_ppx_deriving (version: n/a)
ppx_sexp_message    (version: 113.24.00)
ppx_sexp_value      (version: 113.24.00)
sexplib             (version: 113.24.00)
sexplib.num         (version: 113.24.00)
sexplib.unix        (version: 113.24.00)
```

which to my novice eyes suggests that sexplib.syntax doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that this is a bug, induced by a recent transition of the core suite from camlp4 to ppx. It should be fixed in `113.24.01`, so make sure that you have

```
 opam update
 opam upgrade
```

and then install the latest version:

```
 opam install core.113.24.01
```

If this doesn't help, then the other option, would be to fallback to an older version, before the transition, something like

```
 opam install core.113.00.00
```

In order to prevent automatic upgrade of the library, you can pin it:

```
 opam pin add core 113.00.00
```

Comment: I keep having this issue even after update/upgrade: `ocamlfind list | grep sexplib` does not list sexplib.syntax

Comment: I tried installing core 113.00.00 first - maybe this is relevant?

Comment: what version of core did you finally get? Did you pin it?

Comment: I pinned it, but later removed the pin (opam pin remove core), then did and update/upgrade.

Comment: @BillyBadBoy: I tried installing core.113.00.00 first, then updating/upgrading. That left me with no core for an unmet dependency `core -> variantslib < 109.16.00`. I ended up switching back to the previous state.

Comment: So, finally, have you succeed? And if not, did you try to install the latest `core.113.24.01`?

Comment: @ivg: no success yet, but core.113.24.01 is installed and reported by `ocamlfind list | grep core`

Answer (score 2):

`core.syntax` is no longer supported starting from the 113.24.00 release. I did a minor release of core (113.24.02) to make it effective.

You should now use `ppx_jane`. It is the equivalent of `core.syntax` for Jane Street ppx rewriters. The *Real World OCaml* instructions have been updated.

You can use `ppx_jane` either as a regular findlib package or directly:

```
(* Regular findlib package *)
# #require "ppx_jane";;
(* Directly *)
# #ppx "ppx-jane -as-ppx";;
```

Comment: I have ppx_jane and sexplib installed but sitll could not make the following work `type t = { foo: int; bar: float } with sexp ;;` with core-0.9.1

Answer (score 1):

An aspect that hasn't been mentionned above is that installing the opam package `sexplib` is not enough to get the findlib `sexplib.syntax`, even with version 113.00.00 or earlier: be sure to also install opam package `type_conv`